# return a new dictionary with the name of foods as keys and its quantity as value

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, key-value

```
get_quantities({'t1': ['Vegetarian stew', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't3': ['Steak pie', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't4': ['Steak pie', 'Steak pie']})
```

this is my dictionary. `t` refers to tables.

i need to return a new dictionary:

```
{'Vegetarian stew': 3, 'Poutine': 2, 'Steak pie': 3} like this.
```

how can i write this code?

Comment: Show some effort in researching please. Try searching for some tutorials about dictionaries and try to do it by yourself. If you have any problem with the code you've tried, come to StackOverflow and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def get_quantities(tables):
    counter = Counter()
    for table in tables.iterValues():
        counter.update(table)
    return counter
```

This will return a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), which is a dictionary-like object.

For example,

```
quantities = get_quantities({'t1': ['Vegetarian stew', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't3': ['Steak pie', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 't4': ['Steak pie', 'Steak pie']})
print quantities['Vegetarian stew']
```

will print `3`.